# Why do I run out of memory when training with a large dataset, but have no problems with a small dataset?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I'm trying to build a keypoint detection system using Keras. I've got a UNet like model, with a series of convolutions, batch normalization, and max pooling, followed by a symmetric series of up sampling, convolution, and batch normalization layers (and skip connections). When given 100 instances, I'm able to call `model.fit()` without a problem. However, if I leave the model the same but use 500 instances, Keras crashes with an OOM exception. Why does this happen, and is there anything I can do to fix it?

Here's (what I think is) the relevant part of the code where I call `model.fit`:

```py
model = build_model(
    filters=50,
    filter_step=1,
    stages=5,
    stage_steps=1,
    initial_convolutions=0,
    stacks=1,
)

print(model.summary()) 

dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((X, y))
dataset = dataset.batch(1)

model.fit(
    dataset,
    epochs=2**7,
    callbacks=[
        EarlyStopping(monitor="loss", patience=5, min_delta=1e-7, start_from_epoch=10),
        LearningRateScheduler(step_decay)
    ],
)
```

`X` and `y` are Numpy arrays with the following shapes:

- `X`: (100, 1024, 1024, 3)
- `y`: (100, 1024, 1024)

100 here is the data set size. If I increase this to 500 (or more), I get the out-of-memory exception. It appears to me that Keras is perhaps trying to load the entire data set into memory, despite using `from_tensor_slices` and `batch(1)`, so I'm clearly misunderstanding something.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> When you use `tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((X, y))`, TensorFlow
> attempts to create a dataset where each element is a pair `(X[i], y[i])`. If the dataset is too large, this can consume a significant
> amount of memory, especially if X and y are large.

To address this memory issue, we can modify the data loading process using a generator to load the data in batches, during runtime.

You'll have to define a generator that yields batches of data `(X_batch, y_batch)` and then to create the dataset use:

`tf.data.Dataset.from_generator`

Full documentation [here](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/data/Dataset#from_generator).

**And an example could look like this:**

```
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf

# Assume X and y are your data
X = np.random.rand(500, 1024, 1024, 3)
y = np.random.rand(500, 1024, 1024)

# Define a generator to yield batches of data
def data_generator(X, y, batch_size):
    num_samples = X.shape[0]
    for i in range(0, num_samples, batch_size):
        yield X[i:i+batch_size], y[i:i+batch_size]

# Parameters
batch_size = 16

# Create a generator
generator = data_generator(X, y, batch_size)

# Create a tf.data.Dataset using the generator
dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_generator(
    lambda: generator,
    output_signature=(
        tf.TensorSpec(shape=(None, 1024, 1024, 3), dtype=tf.float32),
        tf.TensorSpec(shape=(None, 1024, 1024), dtype=tf.float32)
    )
)

# Model and training code would go here...
```

Answer (score -1):

Tensorflow `from_tensor_slices` is not efficient for memory and it loads all the data to the memory as the [documentation](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/data#consuming_numpy_arrays) says:

> If all of your input data fits in memory, the simplest way to create a `Dataset` from them is to convert them to `tf.Tensor` objects and use `Dataset.from_tensor_slices`.
>
> **Note:** The above code snippet will embed the features and labels arrays in your TensorFlow graph as tf.constant() operations. This works well for a small dataset, but wastes memory---because the contents of the array will be copied multiple times---and can run into the 2GB limit for the tf.GraphDef protocol buffer.

To stream big datasets without memory limit, you can use `tf.data.TFRecordDataset` as [documentation](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/data#consuming_tfrecord_data) referred.

> The `tf.data` API supports a variety of file formats so that you can process **large datasets that do not fit in memory**. For example, the TFRecord file format is a simple record-oriented binary format that many TensorFlow applications use for training data. The `tf.data.TFRecordDataset` class enables you to stream over the contents of one or more TFRecord files as part of an input pipeline.

What you have to do is to convert your dataset to `TFRecord` format. There are some tutorials about converting datasets to TFRecord format. These links may help. [link 0](https://medium.com/nerd-for-tech/how-to-create-tensorflow-tfrecords-out-of-any-dataset-c64c3f98f4f8), [link 1](https://keras.io/examples/keras_recipes/creating_tfrecords/), [link 2](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/research/object_detection/g3doc/using_your_own_dataset.md)